# Pip freeze doesnt show freshly installed packages with Pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, pycharm, virtualenv

I use Pycharm to create and manage my virtualenvs in my projects.

The problem is that after adding a library with pycharm, when I type the command (`pip3 freeze --user`), the library does not appear in the command result.

I have to manually type the `pip install` command each time so that the library is visible.

What manipulation should I do in PyCharm to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean you have to re-install it so it is "visible"?

Answer (score 5):

For what you are saying, the first thing that comes to mind is that you should use:

```
pip freeze
```

And not

```
pip3 freeze
```

Because the command mapped to the `pip` version when you have virtualenv activated is the first. Note that for installing you seem to use `pip`, and not `pip3`

Moreover, the `--user` option afaik is related to the packages installed in the user folder:

> ```
> --user      Install to the Python user install directory for your platform. Typically 
>
> ~/.local/, or %APPDATA%\Python on
>              Windows. (See the Python documentation for site.USER_BASE for full details.)
> ```

If your packages are installed in the virtualenv folder, I would tell you to not use that option.

Also please make sure you have your virtualenv activated. In linux you can do so by `source path/to/virtualenv/activate`

#### Edit

I understand that the reason you are using `pip3` is because you may have different versions of Python in your machine. Let me explain you a bit further how it works, because version management is usually a headache for many programmers and it is common to find problems when doing so.

If you install different versions of Python in your linux machine, and you do that as root, then the installation will proceed for the whole system. Usually Python2 installation folder for Linux machines is `/usr/bin/python`. However, I am uncertain of which directory is used for Python3 installations. You can check that easily by doing `whereis python3`. You can serach the path to binary of any command by doing `whereis command`. Note that this works also for `whereis python` as far as you don't have `virtualenv` activated.

Aditionally, the link to the binary of a command (or the set of instructions to be exectued, more broadly) is defined in certain folders in Linux, depending on whether you created the command as root or as a user, and possibly also on the distro. This works differently in Windows, that uses the Registry Edit utility to handle command mappings. When you enable your virtualenv, what you are doing is creating an environment that enables mapping system commands such as `python` to the Python installation in your virtualenv folder.

When you disable the virtualenv, the command points again to the default installation path. Same happens with pip, so incorrect usage of this tool may result in different packages being installed in different locations, and therefore not appearing available for the right Python version at any given circumstance.

> In Linux, environment variables are shell dependent, though you can write them out with echo $variable and set them with variable=value (from bash). The search path is simply called PATH and you can get yours by typing echo $PATH.

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/262073/426469

I encourage you to check other questions in SE network such as this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42211/96121, to learn more about this.

#### Addendum

*Quick tip*: it is common to use the `pip freeze` command as follows:
    pip freeze > requirements.txt

It is a standard that leads to understanding that modules in such file are required for the correct functioning of your application. That lets you easily exclude the `virtualenv` folder when you install the program in another computer, since you can readily know the requriments for a fresh installation. However, you can use the command as you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just realized I was using a bad workflow in my pip usage (I installed packages globally with the bash while pycharm installed them locally)

Comment: You're welcome :) @etaurrnetvalent feel free to accept my answer if you think it solved your problem